# Matlab c2d(1/s) is different than z transform tables

Tags: control, control-system, matlab

[c2d](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html) is used to convert a model from continuous to discrete time. The official doc states:

> sysd = c2d(sysc,Ts) discretizes the continuous-time dynamic system model sysc using zero-order hold on the inputs and a sample time of Ts.

Why is it that when I do:

```
>> c2d(1/s, 1)
```

I get:

```
ans =

    1
  -----
  z - 1

Sample time: 1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.
```

but according to Z-transform tables the z transform of `1/s` is

```
ans =

    z
  -----
  z - 1
```

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: Probably the integration method. c2d uses the zero order hold by default. Z transform table might use another method.

Comment: The Z-transform table is the result of the backward rectangular rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sys = c2d (sys, tsam, method)
```

If you do not include the method it will use zero-order hold

```matlab
c2d(G,1,'zoh')
```

resulting in 
$$ \frac{1}{z-1} $$

If you pick a different conversion method it gives you different results, but notice that the poles stability will be "conserved"

```matlab
c2d(G,1,'tustin')
```

results in 
$$ \frac{0.5z+0.5}{z-1} $$

```matlab
c2d(G,1,'impulse')
```

results in 
$$ \frac{z}{z-1} $$

```matlab
c2d(G,1,'matched')
```

results in 
$$ \frac{1.052}{z-1} $$